# Realization of Bessel functions

Tags: special-functions

As I know when whe trying to execute Bessel functions when $z < 8$ we using this formula
$$J_\nu(z) = (\frac{1}{2}z)^\nu \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\frac{1}{4}z^2)^k}{k!\Gamma(\nu+k+1)}$$
And thats formula I found when $z \geq 8$ 
$$J_\nu(z) \simeq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}[\cos(z - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4})P_\nu(z) - \sin(z - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4})Q_v(z)]$$
So, please, could you help me to understand what is and how to execute $P_\nu(z)$ and $Q_v(z)$ here?

Comment: You could be interested in what the DLMF (Digital Library of Mathematical Functions) has to say for the Bessel functions. Here is the link: http://dlmf.nist.gov/10 .

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano oh thanks I'll look trough it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, yep, i found it!
It's about Hankel asymptotic expansions and looks like
$$
P_\nu(z) \equiv 1 - \frac{(\nu,2)}{(2z)^2} + \frac{(\nu,4)}{(2z)^4} - \dots 
$$
$$
Q_\nu(z) \equiv \frac{(\nu,1)}{(2z)}
 - \frac{(\nu,3)}{(2z)^3} + \frac{(\nu,5)}{(2z)^5} - \dots $$
where
$$
(\nu,m) = \frac{(4\nu^2 - 1^2)(4\nu^2 - 3^2) \dots (4\nu^2 - (2m -1)^2)}{2^{2m} m!}, m = 1,2,3,\cdots
$$