# Can $J_{1}(z)$ be expressed as a series in decreasing powers of $z$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, bessel-functions

Let $J_{\nu}(z)$ denote the Bessel function of the first kind. Then, according to [this page](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/17/01/01/), we have the recurrence relation

$$\displaystyle J_{\nu}(z) = \frac{2(\nu + 1)}{z}J_{\nu + 1}(z) - J_{\nu + 2}.$$

Taking $\nu = 1$, we can inductively express $J_{1}$ in the following ways:

$$\displaystyle J_{1}(z) = \frac{4}{z}J_{2}(z) - J_{3}(z)$$
$$\displaystyle = \frac{4}{z}\left( \frac{6}{z}J_{3}(z) - J_{4}(z) \right) - \left( \frac{8}{z}J_{4}(z) - J_{5}(z) \right)$$
$$\displaystyle = \ ...$$

Thus, my question is: can we write

$$\displaystyle J_{1}(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}J_{\nu_n}(z)}{z^{n}}$$

for some real coefficients $a_i$ and indices $\nu_i$, or something similar?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363235/realization-of-bessel-functions) question seems to suggest that we can, for large $z$.

Equation 10.17.3 [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17) also seems relevant, except without the Bessel functions appearing in the summands. I am particularly interested if it is possible to come up with a series starting with $z^{-1}$ rather than $z^0$.

Comment: With decreasing powers of $z$ ... you may want it to converge near $+\infty$.  (Jack showed it cannot converge near $0$.)  I am guessing even that is not possible, because $J_1(z)$ oscillates.  But I have no proof.

Comment: @GEdgar: we are dealing with entire functions: how can we have convergence in a left neighbourhood of $+\infty$ without having convergence in a right neighbourhood of $0$, too?

Comment: So, maybe it converges in $|z|>5$ or something.  For example $\sum 1/z^n$ converges in $|z| > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

That is clearly not possible: $J_n(x)$ is an entire function, hence $x=0$ is a regular point.
Assuming
$$ J_1(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a_n\,J_{\nu_n}(x)}{x^n} \tag{1}$$
(with $\nu_n\in\mathbb{N}$) holds, we have that $x=0$ is a singularity for $J_1(x)$, contradiction.
However, we have
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(J_n(x)\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}\left(s+\sqrt{1+s^2}\right)^n}\tag{2} $$
that can be used to produce similar identities through geometric series expansion and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$.